# Has anybody installed Gazebo 8 with Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to install Gazebo 8 on Ubuntu 14.04.
I can compile the code successfully, but it does not show any thing or printing anything in the console.
I will appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15304/has-anybody-installed-gazebo-8-with-ubuntu-14.04?/) by [Reza](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3024/reza/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 8 is only officially supported on Ubuntu 16.04+.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The previous answer is right. Gazebo8 is only available in Ubuntu 16.04+. If you need to run gazebo8 on Trusty I recommend to use the gazebo8 docker image as soon as it hits the OSRF docker hub. The nvidia-docker extension is particularly useful. There is some documentation in [Steve's Peters github](https://bitbucket.org/scpeters/unix-stuff/src/4a1228a910c2/gazebo8-docker/?at=master) about how to make nvidia-docker to work properly with gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2